# Server socket doesn't work properly - "accept is already open"

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I've tried to separate my server socket in a singleton. Here's the code:

ServerSocket.h

```
#pragma once
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using asio::ip::tcp;

class ServerSocket
{
public:
    ServerSocket(ServerSocket& otherSingleton) = delete;
    void operator=(const ServerSocket& copySingleton) = delete;

    tcp::acceptor* InitAcceptor();
    tcp::socket* InitSocket();
    void StartServerSocket();
    void SendData(std::string);
    std::array<char, 5000> RecieveData();

    static ServerSocket* GetInstance();
private:
    static ServerSocket* instance;

    tcp::acceptor* acceptor;
    tcp::socket* socket;
    asio::io_context io_context;

    ServerSocket() {
        acceptor = InitAcceptor();
        socket = InitSocket();
    }

    ~ServerSocket()
    {
        std::cout << "Server closed";
    }
};
```

ServerSocket.cpp

```
#include "ServerSocket.h"

tcp::acceptor* ServerSocket::InitAcceptor()
{
    try
    {
        tcp::acceptor* acceptor = new tcp::acceptor(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 27015));

        return acceptor;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

tcp::socket* ServerSocket::InitSocket()
{
    try
    {
        tcp::socket* socket = new tcp::socket(io_context);

        return socket;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

void ServerSocket::StartServerSocket()
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << "Server started";
        for (;;)
        {
            acceptor->accept(*socket);
        };
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

std::array<char, 5000> ServerSocket::RecieveData()
{
    try {
        std::array<char, 5000> buf;
        asio::error_code error;

        size_t len = socket->read_some(asio::buffer(buf), error);
        buf[len] = '\0';
        return buf;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

ServerSocket* ServerSocket::instance(nullptr);

ServerSocket* ServerSocket::GetInstance()
{
    if (instance == nullptr)
    {
        instance = new ServerSocket();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Server socket starts, I get:

```
Server started
```

when a client connects, I get:

```
accept: Already open
```

and the server stops.

I think the error comes from the acceptor being in a for function. But according to the docs, it should work this way. (or at least that's how I understand - https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.20.0/doc/asio/tutorial/tutdaytime2.html)

I tried deleting the for loop, like this:

```
try
    {
        std::cout << "Server started";
        acceptor->accept(*socket);
    }
```

and now there is no problem. But the connection isn't kept open by the server. The client connects once, sends data, and the server stops running.

As far as I understand from the docs, if I set the acceptor in a for(;;), it should be running - but it doesn't work in my case.

So, how can I keep my socket open in my implementation? I want it to be running for more than one SendData - I want it to be able to communicate with the client as long as the client is connected.

Thanks.

//Edit:

Here's the client code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <asio.hpp>
#include "../../cereal/archives/json.hpp"

using asio::ip::tcp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    try
    {
        if (argc != 2)
        {
            std::cerr << "Usage: client <host>" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        // Socket Parameters
        const unsigned port = 27015;
        auto ip_address = asio::ip::make_address_v4(argv[1]);
        auto endpoint = tcp::endpoint{ ip_address, port };

        // Creating and Connecting the Socket
        asio::io_context io_context;
        auto resolver = tcp::resolver{ io_context };
        auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(endpoint);

        auto socket = tcp::socket{ io_context };
        asio::connect(socket, endpoints);

        std::array<char, 5000> buf;
        std::cout << "Message to server: ";

        asio::error_code ignored_error;

        std::string username = "test", password = "mihai";
        std::stringstream os;
        {
            cereal::JSONOutputArchive archive_out(os);
            archive_out(
                CEREAL_NVP(username),
                CEREAL_NVP(password)
            );
        }

        asio::write(socket, asio::buffer(os.str()), ignored_error);
        return 0;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
```

And Communication.h which is responsible to catching the operation from the client and sending it to the server

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "DBUser.h"
#include "DBPost.h"

class Communication
{
public:
    enum class Operations {
        eLogin,
        eRegister
    };
    void ExecuteOperation(Operations operation,const std::array<char, 5000>& buffer);
};
```

.cpp

```
#include "Communication.h"

void Communication::ExecuteOperation(Operations operation,const std::array<char, 5000>& buffer)
{
    DBUser* user= DBUser::getInstance();
    switch (operation)
    {
    case Communication::Operations::eLogin:
    {
        std::string username, password;
        std::stringstream is(buffer.data());
        {
            cereal::JSONInputArchive archive_in(is);
            archive_in(username,password);
        }
        try
        {
            user->LoginUser(username, password);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cout << e.what();
        }
        break;
    }
    case Communication::Operations::eRegister:
    {
        std::string username, password;
        std::stringstream is(buffer.data());
        {
            cereal::JSONInputArchive archive_in(is);
            archive_in(username, password);
        }
        try
        {
            user->CreateUser(username, password);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cout << e.what();
        }
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>
#include "DBLink.h"
#include "DBUser.h"
#include "DBPost.h"
#include "../Logging/Logging.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <asio.hpp>
#include "ServerSocket.h"
#include "Communication.h"

int main()
{
    ServerSocket* test = ServerSocket::GetInstance();
    test->StartServerSocket();

    std::array<char, 5000> buf = test->RecieveData();
    Communication communicationInterface;
    communicationInterface.ExecuteOperation(Communication::Operations::eRegister, buf);
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: I think that what you want to do is easier if you use async instead of sync. Hard to think about a single threaded sync server which is listening for new connections and at the same time reads client messages. Also I can not see where you read something?

Comment: @KoronisNeilos I didn't include that part because the problem is from the server - so the client part would not be necessary. (in my opinion)

Comment: If you want the server to read the message from the client you need to call read on the server

Comment: May you post a working example and explain what you want to do? Do you want to write a sync server which takes one client and prints everything what the client sends?

Comment: I want the client to connect. Then client sends data to server -> server responds. Client sends another data -> server responds etc. The problem is that after the server responds once, the connection is closed.

Comment: I think you have to show more code. Do you have a server and a client program? May you post the source code for the server?

Comment: This is the source code for the server socket.

Comment: Just to be clear, your `for loop` calls `accept` on `*socket` and then -- without closing `*socket` -- calls `acceptor->accept(*socket)` again.  So you call `accept` on a socket descriptor that is already in a connected state -- hence the error.  Note that your code is quite different from that in the [link you posted](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.20.0/doc/asio/tutorial/tutdaytime2/src.html).

Comment: So, how can I keep the socket alive for more than one request?

Comment: My guess is that your server makes a connection but then it does nothing with it . So you should write a read function and  put something like  "socket->read(socket,buffer); inside a magic loop". But hard to tell if you do not post more code.

Comment: I added more code.

Comment: I didn't add yet more requests, because I've observed that server stops after one.

Comment: I can not see the usage of the class "ServerSocket" and where you call read

Comment: You might want to look at the [chat client/server example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp11_examples.chat).

Comment: @KoronisNeilos I added that too.\

Comment: Your server needs to call read on the socket then write something back to the client.
The client needs to call read on the socket to read the response form the server.
check this example "https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp".
I whould sugest try to compile the example and then try to send a message from your client to it and read the response.

Comment: "std::array<char, 5000> buf = test->RecieveData();" Where is the RecieveData() function?

Comment: @KoronisNeilos it's in ServerSocket, I added it now. I'm sorry - I don't know why I didn't add it. Can you help me? I don't really know how to keep the socket alive - I'm a beginner in networking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of antipattern going on.

1. Overuse of pointers.
2. Overuse of `new` (without any `delete`, a guaranteed leak)
3. The destructor claims that "Server closed" but it doesn't actually do a single thing to achieve that.
4. Two-step initialization (InitXXXX functions). Firstly, you should obviously favor initializer lists

   ```
   ServerSocket()
    : acceptor_(InitAcceptor()), socket_(InitSocket())
   { }
   ```

   And you need to make`InitAcceptor`/`InitSocket` private to the implementation.
5. I'll forget the Singleton which is anti-pattern 99% of the time, but I guess that's *almost* debatable.

In your `StartServerSocket` you have a loop that reuses the same `socket` all the time. Of course, it will already be connected. You need separate socket instances:

```
    for (;;) {
        acceptor_->accept(*socket_);
    };
```

### Simplify/Fix

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;

struct Listener {
    void Start()
    {
        std::cout << "Server started";
        for (;;) {
            auto socket = acceptor_.accept();
            std::cout << "Accepted connection from " << socket.remote_endpoint()
                      << std::endl;
        };
    }

    static Listener& GetInstance() {
        static Listener s_instance{27015}; // or use weak_ptr for finite lifetime
        return s_instance;
    }

  private:
    asio::io_context ioc_; // order of declaration is order of init!
    tcp::acceptor    acceptor_;

    Listener(uint16_t port) : acceptor_{ioc_, tcp::endpoint{tcp::v4(), port}} {}
};

int main() {
    try {
        Listener::GetInstance().Start();
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Now you could hand the `socket` instances to a thread. I concur with the other commenters that thread-per-request is likely *also* an anti-pattern, and you should consider using async IO with Asio (hence the name).

### Live Demo

[image]

Comment: Note my answer was written to the initial version of the question https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70275611/1

Comment: I looked into your solution now, but I don't know how to do two things: first, not having a socket, I don't know how to read data from the client. second, the client connection closes - I want it to be opened until the terminal window is closed / the execution stopped by the user.

Comment: You have the socket. Like I said you have to do something with it (I even recommended using s asynchronous IO). If you require a lot more guidance outside it is better to start from an example. Alternatively you could ask a new, targeted question. I know I you've expanded the question but that's really not how this site works, it just causes or questions with badly matching answers.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT complete and working example based on the server code from the question:

```cpp
// main.cxx
#include "ServerSocket.hxx"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int
main ()
{
  ServerSocket *test = ServerSocket::GetInstance ();
  test->StartServerSocket ();
  std::cout << std::endl;
  while (auto msg = test->RecieveData ())
    {
      std::cout << msg.value ();
    }
}
```

```cpp
// ServerSocket.hxx
#pragma once
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class ServerSocket
{
public:
  ServerSocket (ServerSocket &otherSingleton) = delete;
  void operator= (const ServerSocket &copySingleton) = delete;

  tcp::acceptor *InitAcceptor ();
  tcp::socket *InitSocket ();
  void StartServerSocket ();
  void SendData (std::string);
  std::optional<std::string> RecieveData ();

  static ServerSocket *GetInstance ();

private:
  static ServerSocket *instance;

  tcp::acceptor *acceptor;
  tcp::socket *socket;
  boost::asio::io_context io_context;

  ServerSocket ()
  {
    acceptor = InitAcceptor ();
    socket = InitSocket ();
  }

  ~ServerSocket () { 
    delete socket;
    delete acceptor;
    std::cout << "Server closed"; }
};
```

```cpp
// ServerSocket.cxx
#include "ServerSocket.hxx"
#include <optional>

tcp::acceptor *
ServerSocket::InitAcceptor ()
{
  try
    {
      return new tcp::acceptor (io_context, tcp::endpoint (tcp::v4 (), 27015));
    }
  catch (std::exception &e)
    {
      std::cerr << e.what () << std::endl;
    }
  return nullptr;
}

tcp::socket *
ServerSocket::InitSocket ()
{
  try
    {
      return new tcp::socket (io_context);
    }
  catch (std::exception &e)
    {
      std::cerr << e.what () << std::endl;
    }
  return nullptr;
}

void
ServerSocket::StartServerSocket ()
{
  try
    {
      std::cout << "Server started";
      acceptor->accept (*socket);
    }
  catch (std::exception &e)
    {
      std::cerr << e.what () << std::endl;
    }
}

std::optional<std::string>
ServerSocket::RecieveData ()
{
  try
    {
      char data[5000];
      for (;;)
        {
          boost::system::error_code error;
          size_t length = socket->read_some (boost::asio::buffer (data), error);
          if (error == boost::asio::error::eof) return std::nullopt; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
          else if (error)
            throw boost::system::system_error (error); // Some other error.
          return std::string{ data, length };
        }
    }
  catch (std::exception &e)
    {
      std::cerr << e.what () << std::endl;
    }
  return {};
}

ServerSocket *ServerSocket::instance (nullptr);

ServerSocket *
ServerSocket::GetInstance ()
{
  if (instance == nullptr)
    {
      instance = new ServerSocket ();
    }
  return instance;
}
```

Note that there are still some problems with the server:

- Error handling
- More than one connection
- The server does not send a message if the operation was successful
- If you disconnect the client the server shuts down
- We could replace some pointers with optional no need to write "new"
- Just make a normal class do not write it as singleton.

If you like to test the server you can run

```
telnet localhost 27015
```

and then write some text and press enter

Comment: This can't be the solution for sure. What this will do is to register my user forever. I don't want that - I want to make the server be alive for as many requests the client makes. Now, if I send some data once from the client to the server, the server will stop. I don't want that - I want the server to be up for as many requests as the client wants. The server should stop only when the client disconnects.

Comment: I did an update. I hope it now works for you.